# APNS Push Notifications are sent but not received on iOS device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

After researching a lot Ive found out that this is a popular problem, but Im posting a new question because none of them was helpful to solve my problem.

Im following [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) in order to create `Push Notifications` for an `iOS` device.

It look's like everything is working fine, because when I execute the `simplepush.php` code it returns

> Connected to APNS
>
> Message successfully delivered

but the device doesn`t receive any push messages.

A few keypoints:

- Yes, its a developer certificate and it is communicating to the `sandbox` server. There`s no messing around with Production issues.
- When testing it with [Pusher](https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher) it returns a "APN Invalid Token" log, although I think the token is being generated correctly.

And this is how Im getting the token on the `AppDelegate.m` file:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
        
    }
    else
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }
    
    return YES;
}

#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    //register to receive notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
{
    //handle the actions
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"declineAction"]){
    }
    else if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"answerAction"]){
    }
}
#endif

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to get Token, error: %@",error);
}
```

Token response when launching the app (looks OK to me):

> 2015-12-03 13:27:27.930 PushChat[598:246912] My token is:  8a0b645c 46c0547a 3078be82 52b4a82d 9b579530 fb9a902d>

### What could possibly be going on?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am getting the same problem! Thanks.

Comment: Yes I did. If you're not receiving the push notifications it's because there is something wrong with your certificates.

Comment: thanks for you reply. Do you remember what whas wrong exactly? I followed step by step the reywenderlich tutorial...

Comment: I recommend to do it again with lots of attention. If you generate a certificate from a wrong key file, it won't work. Check if your application bundle id matches the App Id that you created at apple. Then check if your certificate for APNS is correctly linked to the App Id and it's Provisioning Profile.

Comment: I will take a look, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Just solved the same issue. In my case the problem had nothing to do with certificates or private key, instead it was related to a wildcard App Id. I have an application bundle wich I use for many business apps, so I have a wildcard app id **com.domain.*** and a set of provisioning profile associated (development, appstore, adhoc). I knew that in order to use Push Notifications a unique App Id was needed, in fact XCode generated automatically the unique App ID from the wildcard one. But this was not enough: the provisioning profile was still connected to the wildcard App Id. I had to sign the target with a new **unique** Provisioning Profile (I used the XCode autogenerated one) directly associated with the **com.domain.appname** unique app id. Definitely, if you want to use push notifications you can't use one provisioning profile for multiple apps, but you had to create a provisioning profile for each app id.

> If you plan to use services such as Game Center, In-App Purchase, and
>   Push Notifications, or want a Bundle ID unique to a single app, use an
>   explicit App ID.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the device console and filter the device log with APP bundle ID. If there's any error info relevant to "push notification", then the problem should be in the "aps" payload you send to the device. Otherwise, it should be the network issue that the device cannot connect to APN server.